# will/can solr, elasticsearch and kibana out perform sql server's cube technologies?

Tags: solr

This trio of products came up as an alternative to sql server for searching and presenting analytics over a survey based pattern of about 100 million data points. A survey pattern is basically questions x answers x forms x studies and in our case very qa oriented about how people did their jobs.  About 7% of our data points cannot be quantified because they are comments.

So, can this community envision (perhaps provide a link to a success story) leveraging these products for slicing and dicing metrics (via drag and drop) along with comments over 100 million data points and out performing sql server?  Our metrics can be $'s, scores, counts, hours depending on the question.  We have at least two hierarchies, one over people and the other over depts.  Both are temporal in that depending on the date, have different relationships (aka changing dimensions). In all there are about 90 dimensions for each data point depending on how you count the hierarchy levels.

Answer (score 0):

You cant compare SQL engine and elasticsearch/solr.

It depends how you want to query it: join or not, full text search or not etc...

Answer (score 0):

Like Thomas said, it depends. Depends on your data and how you want to query it. In general, for text oriented data then NoSQL will be better and provide more functionalities than SQL. However, if I understand correctly, only 7% of your data is text focused (the comments), so I assume the rest is structured.

In terms of performance, it depends what kind of text analysis you want to do and what kind of queries you're wanting to recreate. For example, joining is usually much simpler and quicker in SQL than its non-relational equivalent. You could set up a basic Solr instance, recreate some of your text related SQL queries in [Solr SQL equivalents](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/parallel-sql-interface.html), and see how it performs on your data in comparison.

While overall, NoSQL is usually touted as better at scaling, it's highly dependent on your data and requirements as to which of the two would be better in certain situations.

Comment: don't want to overstay my welcome but this might help.  1) Text stuff is key based retrieval only (eg review #)  2) short of perhaps the hierarchies, I don't see a need for joining.  I'm picturing serialized records, one for each "review".  There are many reviews in one single study.  A review is basically how a person handled an individual customer account.  The serialized attributes within a study would match (not value wise) but not necessarily across studies.  3)  a slicer would be necessary unless someone has already built one.  4) main objective query wise is aggregation of the metrics